# SQL 2012 Column Reverts Back to Not Allowing Nulls

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012. There's a column of data type `int` that I want it to allow nulls. I check the **Allow Nulls** option for the column but after a few minutes it reverts back to being unchecked.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried `ALTER TABLE` in a query window instead of using a GUI to point, click, wait?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - no, I didn't try that. I never thought it would make a difference.

Comment: Once you get comfortable using a sql statement instead of the UI to alter tables, insert data etc you will find that you never open the designers again. They are way slower for the developer and sometimes just don't really work all that well.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname int NULL;`

Comment: There's no way on earth anybody could do that faster with the UI than I just typed it... and since the UIs take all kinds of excessive locks and, as Sean said, don't really work all that well...

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` command failed because an index is dependent on that column. That explains why the UI didn't work! Now, can I just drop an index, alter the column and then recreate the index? Any potential pitfalls?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - do you want to submit an answer?